# Undercover agency hideout

Tags: geography, near-future, earth, cities, concealment

In my world half the population is dead, the rest enslaved after the uprising of a nefarious rebel faction. Most of the world's armies have succumbed to defeat. However, a group of former intelligence operatives have banded together to form the world's last chance at resistance. However, being hunted by the most powerful organisation in the world they need a safe place to stay, where they will not be tracked or found. Their hideout must confine to one rule specifically though, it has to be relatively close to a city.

This world is in essence just an alternate Earth where history is laid out the same way until ~2020 when the timelines diverge, meaning there is no magic and due to the death of many leading world scientists and the survivors refusing to cooperate technology does not advance, meaning technology is limited to current day or very near completion. But your hideout can be as creative as you like as long as it conforms to these rules.

The question: Where could the resistance group create a hideout near a city in which they cannot be tracked?

Comment: Hi Bisqwit, and welcome! I don't see an answerable question here. What exactly do you want to learn by asking this? Please take the quick site [tour], review [How do I ask a good question?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then [edit] your question to identify an answerable question that falls within our scope.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling that better?

Comment: It's better. I'm still not completely convinced that this is a great fit for our site, but at least your edit helps with the unclearness of the original question. I also changed the tags to try to better categorize the question.

Comment: How can the histories be same up until 2020? Last I checked, it was only 2017 in the real timeline... (Also, welcome to the site.)

Answer (score 1):

So you assume that the world clenching faction look for some guys so they need to hide.

That assumption is wrong. If you have an army of hundreds of thousands you just wait for those few to come to you. And yes, they may kill thousands of your conscripts but you don't care. Your army may fire hundred rounds from a thousands rifles and it only take one of the bullets to reach your opponents head.

So they don't hide. They are in the open, meeting for coffe and making funny drawnings on napkins, they go to fishing trips for a weekend. They own a bike shop with metal rods and anvils and vices. They own a pharmacy with all those nifty bottles. They work as a security guard in the OmniEerieLooking building in the capitol.

Because they, as a modern poet Marshall Mathers said, need only one shot. One opportunity.